# Check if an object exists in another models foreignkey field

Tags: django

I have a reviewing system for Subjects. User can **review** a subject, and users can **like** that review.

```
class UserReview(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    review = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    likes = GenericRelation('Like')

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'object_id', 'user'),)
```

How do I check if a `user` (eg UserA) exist in the `likes` of a user review? For now I am doing this way:

```
if user_review_obj.likes.filter(user=UserA).count() > 0:
    // exist...
```

But I am hoping there is another better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists`, however the correct usage is

```
if user_review_obj.likes.filter(user=UserA).exists():
    # . . .
```